# Обход части элементов графа для загрузки всех родителей

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графы

Есть набор элементов ориентированного графа. Каждый элемент содержит ссылки на родительские элементы (которых может и не быть в наборе). И есть функция, которая может вернуть по идентификатору элемента все его родительские (вплоть до корневого элемента). Цель - минимизировать вызовы этой функции. Т.е. например, в такой ситуации
[image: ситуация №1]

логично вызвать функцию только для **Node4** (в результате функция вернет все ноды - 1-5).

А в ситуации №2

[image: ситуация №2]

вероятно функцию нужно вызывать для всех элементов в наборе.

Видится такой алгоритм:

1. для каждого элемента в наборе проверить наличие на него ссылки в других элементах набора
2. при отсутствие ссылок поместить элемент в очередь
3. для элементов в очереди вызывать функцию
4. проверить наличие в результах вызовов функции наличие элементов, на которые ссылаются элементы набора, для которых вызова не было
5. при обнаружении ссылки на элемент, который до сих пор не был получен, делать вызов для  элемента набора с этой ссылкой и снова переходить к п.4

Только тут возможна ситуация, когда все элементы имеют ссылку друг на друга (это невозможно в рамках бизнес-логики, но все же не хочется ограничивать алгоритм). Ее нужно обработать отдельно.
Подскажите, верно ли расуждаю, кажется это все уже должно быть придумано и не нужно ничего изобретать.

UDP. Реализовал алгоритм по комментарию *@Stanislav Volodarskiy*

> Для набора элементов сделать топологическую сортировку. По полученному списку пройтись с конца. Для каждого элемента вызывать функцию поиска предков. Найденных предков из списка вычеркивать. Алгоритм гарантирует минимальное количество вызовов функции.

Но получается, что, например, в такой ситуации:
[image: ситуация №3]

выполнив сортировку исходного набора, нужно будет вызвать функцию получения предков для одной из нод (**Node1** или **Node2** в зависимости от сортировки), результат вывоза функции будет содержать **Node4**, **Node3**, **Node1** (или **Node2**). Вычеркнуть из набора мы ничего не сможем, т.к. второго элемента исходного набора в результатах вызова функции нет, а значит нужно выполнить еще один вызов функции для второго элемента в наборе (хотя этот вызов очевидно избыточен!).

Подскажите, правильно ли я понял алгоритм *@Stanislav Volodarskiy* или это ограничение этого алгоритма?

Comment: *Есть набор элементов неориентированного графа. Каждый элемент содержит ссылки на родительские элементы* Это противоречивые сведения. В неориентированном графе нет никакой иерархии, узлы ребра равноправны. На всех рисунках - ориентированный граф.

Comment: @Akina, поправил рисунки и описание

Comment: Теперь на рисунках граф неориентированный. В котором нет и быть не может никаких "детей" и "родителей". Для неориентированного графа "функция, которая может вернуть по идентификатору элемента все его родительские (вплоть до корневого элемента)" должна возвращать всю компоненту связности. Да и какие могут быть "корневые" в неориентированном графе?

Comment: @Akina, т.е. исходная формулировка и рисунки верны при условии, что граф ориентированный?

Comment: Да, вопрос имеет смысл только на ориентированном графе.

Comment: Как велик граф, сколько всего в нём узлов? насколько он изменяется во времени? В общем. подумайте, нет ли смысла заранее преобразовать граф в FQDP (каждый узел содержит атрибут с полным путём до корня)?

Comment: @Akina,  к сожалению, так сделать не сможем, будет слишком затратно на большом количестве элементов. По факту сейчас выполняем вызов этой функции для каждого элемента из набора и потом объединяем в один массив с уникальными элементами.

Comment: А нельзя ли для функции, которая возвращает список предков, ввести мемоизацию? Типа, если она смотрела на список родителей Node4, и по дороге заметеила родителей Node2, то она это запомнила, и при запросе списка родителей Node2 сразу его выдаст. Список родителей можо держать в самом Node или в `Dictionary<Node, List<Node>>`.

Comment: Для набора элементов сделать топологическую сортировку. По полученному списку пройтись с конца. Для каждого элемента вызывать функцию поиска предков. Найденных предков из списка вычеркивать. Алгоритм гарантирует минимальное количество вызовов функции.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, небольшое уточнение. При выполнении топологической сортировки (TS) нужно учитывать только связи между элементами, которые есть в наборе (игнорируя связи с элементами, которых нет в наборе). верно же? и поскольку список, полученный после TS, содержит только элементы из исходного набора, то и вычеркивать можно то их.

Comment: Ответы "да" на оба вопроса.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, обновил вопрос с учетом Вашей рекомендации.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли алгоритм с топологической сортировкой. И да, он не анализирует граф за пределами набора и из-за этого делает лишнюю работу. Это его ограничение. Это максимум что можно сделать глядя только на набор.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, понял!